# Java String Manipulation and dynamic underscore removal

Tags: java, string

Hi i need a basic java program. My input is `___This___is___the___sample___program___` and i want output as This_is_the_sample_program. Underscores are dynamic. There may be 3 or more or less than 3 underscores between the strings. but the output should look like `THis_is_the_sample_program`.

Please help me if anybody knows

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well possible with regex.

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you want [so] to do your homework?

Comment: i dont have any idea to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following: [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String[] split = "___This___is___the___sample___program___".split("_");
int i = 0;
for (; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
    if (split[i].length() > 0) {
        sb.append(split[i]).append("_");
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.append(split[i]));
```